# Как в php получить строку отправленную на сервер посредством ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Встал вопрос получения данных в `php` посредством `ajax` на стороне сервера без использования форм. Маршрутизация работает.

index.php

```
case 'getEntries';
    echo var_dump($_POST);
    break;
```

start.js

```
function some_function() {
    let obj = {id: 'hello5555'};
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/getEntries');
    xhr.send(obj);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

start.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="some_function();">Кнопка</button>
        <script src="start.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Как я могу получить значение `id` в php?

Также как я могу получить в php просто строку из примера ниже

```
function some_function() {
    let obj = 'hello';
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/getEntries');
    xhr.send(obj);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

Понимаю что вопросы достаточно банальные, но я не понимаю как это работает и где взять информацию по такого рода взаимодействию.

Получаю такой ответ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @InDevX с $_POST данных тоже нет

Comment: добавьте пример как Вы post запрос используете

Comment: @InDevX Обновил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отправляйте строку методом POST и читайте из потока `php://input`:

```php
print file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Если хотите отправить объект, то преобразовывайте в JSON:

```js
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Затем декодируйте полученный JSON с помощью `json_decode`:

```php
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print $obj->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю второй вариант, при котором данные будут в $_POST или $_GET:

1. Нужно добавить заголовок (перед xhr.send())

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

2. Нужно написать кастомный сериализатор данных т.к. данные нужно передавать в формате query string ('query=string&...'):

```
function serialize(obj, prefix) {
  let str = [], p;
  for (p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p,
        v = obj[p];
      str.push((v !== null && typeof v === "object") ?
        serialize(v, k) :
        encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
    }
  }
  return str.join("&");
}
```

и уже используя его передаем данные

```js
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(serialize(obj));
```